# How to use switchIfEmpty RxJava

Tags: java, android, rx-java

The logic here is that if the ratings in the database are empty, then I want to get them from the API. I have the following code:

```
Observable.from(settingsRatingRepository.getRatingsFromDB())
            .toList()
            .switchIfEmpty(settingsRatingRepository.getSettingsRatingModulesFromAPI())
            .compose(schedulerProvider.getSchedulers())
            .subscribe(ratingsList -> {
                view.loadRatingLevels(ratingsList, hideLocks);
            }, this::handleError);
```

The `getRatingsFromDB()` call returns `List<SettingRating>`, but the API call returns `Observable<List<SettingRating>>`.

However, when I unit test this, when I pass an empty list from the database call, it does not execute the API call. Can someone pls help me in this matter. This is my unit test code:

```
when(mockSettingsRatingsRepository.getRatingsFromDB()).thenReturn(Collections.emptyList());
List<SettingsRating> settingsRatings = MockContentHelper.letRepositoryReturnSettingsRatingsFromApi(mockSettingsRatingsRepository);

settingsParentalPresenter.onViewLoad(false);

verify(mockView).loadRatingLevels(settingsRatings, false);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @Kiskae mentioned, it's the fact that I am confusing an empty list with an empty Observable. Therefore, I have used the following which is what I want:

```
public void onViewLoad(boolean hideLocks) {
    Observable.just(settingsRatingRepository.getRatingsFromDB())
            .flatMap(settingsRatings -> {
                if (settingsRatings.isEmpty()) {
                    return settingsRatingRepository.getSettingsRatingModules();
                } else {
                    return Observable.just(settingsRatings);
                }
            })
            .compose(schedulerProvider.getSchedulers())
            .subscribe(ratingsList -> {
                view.loadRatingLevels(ratingsList, hideLocks);
            }, this::handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[`Observable#toList()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#toList()) returns a single element. If the observable from which it gets its elements is empty, it will emit an empty list. So by definition the observable will never be empty after calling `toList()`.

Comment: Ah ok, what if I use Observable.just(). The `getRatingsFromDB()` method returns a `List<SettingRating>`, but the API call returns an `Observable<List<SettingRating>>`

Comment: To have it behave as you want it, using `Observable.just()` and then `Observable.filter()` to empty the observable if the list is also empty. so `Observable.just(getRatingsFromDB()).filter(list -> !list.isEmpty())`

Answer (score 4):

`switchIfEmpty` will only be called when your observer completes without emitting any items.
Since you are doing `toList` it will emit list object. Thats why your `switchIfEmpty` is never getting called.

If you want to get data from cache and fallback to your api if cache is empty, use `concat` along with `first` or `takeFirst` operator.

For example:

```
Observable.concat(getDataFromCache(), getDataFromApi())
            .first(dataList -> !dataList.isEmpty());
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on answer by @kiskae, your use of a `toList()` emits the elements aggregated as a single `List`.

There is an alternative to the use of `Observable.just()` + a `flatMap` here.

`Observable.from` will iterate over the list returned by your service and emit each individual items, so an `Observable<Rating>`. If said list is empty, it naturally produces an empty `Observable`. Your API call also produces an `Observable<Rating>`, and in both cases you want to reaggregate that back into a `List<Rating>` for further processing.

So just move the `toList()` from your original code down one line, after the `switchIfEmpty` calling the API:

```
Observable.from(settingsRatingRepository.getRatingsFromDB())
    .switchIfEmpty(settingsRatingRepository.getSettingsRatingModulesFromAPI())
    .toList()
    .compose(schedulerProvider.getSchedulers())
    .subscribe(ratingsList -> {
        view.loadRatingLevels(ratingsList, hideLocks);
    }, this::handleError);
```

Granted, that solution may produce a bit more garbage (as the db's `List` is turned into an `Observable` just to be turned into a new `List` later on).

Comment: I dont think this would work as a drop-in replacement, since `settingsRatingRepository.getSettingsRatingModulesFromAPI()` returns `Observable<List<SettingsRating>>` if I read it correctly.

Comment: Ah, my bad if that's the case