# RxFirebase 'observeSingleValueEvent' implementation prevents it to return empty child values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, rx-java2

I've this query to a firebase database that returns a boolen to indicate a child value exists. I'm using [Rx2Firebase's](https://github.com/FrangSierra/RxFirebase) wrappers to simplify queries:

```
override fun isFavorite(beerId: String): Observable<Boolean> {
        var task = path.child(beerId)
        return RxFirebaseDatabase.observeSingleValueEvent(task) { t -> map(t) }.toObservable()
    }
    private fun map(t: DataSnapshot): Boolean {
        return (t.value ?: false) as Boolean
    }
```

If the query return nulls it should be transformed to false by the 'map' method. Otherwise, it should return true or false according to the child value. The problem is that when there is no child map method is not called.

Looking into `observeSingleValueEvent` implementation there is a filter that prevents map to be called:

```
@NonNull
    public static <T> Maybe<T> observeSingleValueEvent(@NonNull Query query, @NonNull Function<? super DataSnapshot, ? extends T> mapper) {
        return observeSingleValueEvent(query).filter(DataSnapshotMapper.DATA_SNAPSHOT_EXISTENCE_PREDICATE).map(mapper);
    }



static final Predicate<DataSnapshot> DATA_SNAPSHOT_EXISTENCE_PREDICATE = new Predicate<DataSnapshot>() {
    public boolean test(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) throws Exception {
        return dataSnapshot.exists();
    }
};
```

how do I get around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `observeSingleValueEvent(query)` method, and not the one that includes a mapping clause. If the `dataSnapshot` doesn't exists, the map will always cause an exception, that's why the filter is being used there.

To avoid this you should just use the default `observeSingleValueEvent`method of the library.

```
override fun isFavorite(beerId: String): Observable<Boolean> {
        var task = path.child(beerId)
        return RxFirebaseDatabase.observeSingleValueEvent(task).map{ it.exists }.toObservable()
    }
```

Comment: How can one get the exception and return a different result based on this?

`Constants.uidByPhone.child(formattedNumber).observeSingleValueEvent().toObservable().map {
  if (it.exists()) {
     return@map Triple(contact, formattedNumber, it.value)
  } else return@map Triple(contact, formattedNumber, "")
}`

Answer (score 1):

There is switchIfEmpty method or probably use flatMap method of Rx2Firebase. Probably you can get more information here [How to use switchIfEmpty RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39078029/1573414).